# How is the 3000 quota limit in Firebase Remote Config Realtime API on Google Cloud Platform Console calculated?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config

What does the "limit" mean in "Firebase Remote Config Realtime API" on Google cloud console?

Listening to realtime updates on Firebase remote config, "Firebase Remote Config Realtime API" has to be [enabled on GCP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=android#add-real-time-listener).

Firebase doesn't mention anything about the pricing for this but GCP shows 3000 as Limit in Quotas. I'm not sure what does this 3000 mean and how will I be charged if quota is exceeded.

Is there more info available in this?